# Retrieve Salesforce data via Query inside ADF

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory, soql

I wanted to connect to Salesforce and query some data via Azure data factory using SOQL.

I wanted to get the records whose last_date is between  current datetimestamp and 7 days from current datetime stamp.

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYTABLE
WHERE 
last_date!= NULL
AND 
last_date>= :DateTime.now().addDays(-7).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss')
AND
last_date<= :DateTime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss')
```

The above query is giving me a 'SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure' when i use it inside the copydata activity in adf.

Comment: Did you test this query in salesforce dev console?

Comment: that's the problem! at this point sf is just an external source for us and we are not equipped with dev console or workbench to go check. I currently do the preview from adf.

Comment: Does any other simple query works in adf data preview? DO you face issue only with this query?

Comment: the query works but i'm unable to find the logic in soql where i want to extract records whose last_date is between current date and last 7 days (current date - 7 days). the date function to get this done in soql is all going wrong for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAST_N_DAYS:n` date literal to get all the records between today and seven days ago.

**Query:**

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYTABLE
WHERE 
last_date = LAST_N_DAYS:7
```

[image]

**image reference:** [Date Formats and Date Literals in WHERE | SOQL and SOSL Reference | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)